# Grouping Totals by non standard quarters in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table which includes seller, buyer, transaction date, and total.

I want to sum the transactions for each seller by quarters over a given year.  The quarters begin on June 1 and end on May 31.

I know how to sum by the seller for a given date range, but can't figure out how to do it for multiple quarters.

I would like for it to look like

Seller     Q1Total   Q2Total   Q3Total  Q4Total

Seems like something that should be fairly simple but I'm struggling to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select Seller,
       sum(case when Transactiondate between '20150601' and '20150831' then Amount else 0 end) as Q1Amount,
       sum(case when Transactiondate between '20150901' and '20151231' then Amount else 0 end) as Q2Amount,
       sum(case when Transactiondate between '20160101' and '20160229' then Amount else 0 end) as Q3Amount,
       sum(case when Transactiondate between '20160301' and '20160531' then Amount else 0 end) as Q4Amount
from TableName
group by Seller
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgi.  After a couple of tweaks for my data, it worked perfectly for a single year.  Ideally, I would like this to span multiple years, without creating a long list of columns like Q1FY1, Q2FY1...Q1FY3, etc.  Something where each grouping of the Seller's was by year.